# Segmentation fault to the pass double pointer

Tags: c

The following code causes segmentation fault to the pass double pointer to strcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void funcion(char ***ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc(2 * (sizeof(char*)));
    (*ptr)[0] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    (*ptr)[1] = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*ptr[0],"AAAA");
    strcpy(*ptr[1], "BBBB");
}
int main()
{
    char **p;
    funcion(&p);
    printf("%s %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between *ptr[1] and (*ptr)[1]?

Comment: [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment.  Avoid triple pointers whenever you can.

Comment: Subscripting binds tighter than dereferencing.  `*ptr[1]` is `*(ptr[1])` — and it is obviously rather different from `(*ptr)[1]`.  In fact, `*ptr[1]` is equivalent to `ptr[1][0]`, whereas `(*ptr)[1]` is equivalent to `ptr[0][1]`.

Comment: *ptr[1] pass the value while (*ptr)[1] pass pointer?

Comment: They both pass a `char *` because of `char ***ptr` and two levels of subscript/indirection 'remove' two of the stars.  They pass different pointers, that's all.  If you have a regular 2D array of integers, `int x[10][10];`, you don't expect `x[0][1]` necessarily to be the same as `x[1][0]`, do you?

Comment: Why *ptr[1] gives segmentation fault and *ptr[0] not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best ways to cement in your mind the way to handle dereferencing, is too sit down and write the same allocation routine several different ways. All allowable, but as the sound advice in the comments points out, some of the ways make more sense than others. Take your first example, you can pass the *address of a pointer to pointer to char*, but it may not be the best way to go. For example, you can write your `funcion`[sic] in the following manner,

```
/* called passing address of p */
void function (char ***ptr)
{
    *ptr = malloc (2 * sizeof *ptr);

    (*ptr)[0] = malloc (5 * sizeof(char));
    (*ptr)[1] = malloc (5 * sizeof(char));

    strcpy ((*ptr)[0], "AAAA");
    strcpy ((*ptr)[1], "BBBB");
}
```

There is no need to pass anything to your function if all of your allocation and data is contained in the function. You simply need to *assign the return* from the function. For example:

```
/* p simply assigning the address of ptr */
char **function2 (void)
{
    char **ptr = malloc (2 * sizeof *ptr);

    ptr[0] = malloc (5 * sizeof(char));
    ptr[1] = malloc (5 * sizeof(char));

    strcpy (ptr[0], "AAAA");
    strcpy (ptr[1], "BBBB");

    return ptr;
}
```

Since the function allocates memory for the pointers and also allocates storage for the hardcoded `"AAAA"` and `"BBBB"` values, all you need back from the function is the address for `ptr` which you can *assign* to `p`. You simply need to match the function `type` for the required return. You can then access all values from the calling function through `p`.

You can also look at tools available to simplify what it is you are trying to accomplish. For example `strdup` can both allocate and copy a string. You could further simplify `function2` above as:

```
/* a simplified version of funciton2 */
char **function3 (void)
{
    char **ptr = malloc (2 * sizeof *ptr);

    ptr[0] = strdup ("AAAA");
    ptr[1] = strdup ("BBBB");

    return ptr;
}
```

Finally, whenever you allocate data, you need to preserve a pointer to the starting address for each block, so you can `free` the information when it is no longer in use. For your case above, a simple function (which isn't necessarily needed as a function) could be:

```
/* always free all allocated memory */
void free_p (char **p)
{
    free (p[0]);
    free (p[1]);
    free (p);
}
```

Putting that altogether in a bit of test code, you could use all 3 to accomplish the same task:

```
int main (void)
{
    char **p = NULL;

    function (&p);
    printf ("%s %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    free_p (p);

    p = function2();
    printf ("%s %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    free_p (p);

    p = function3();
    printf ("%s %s\n", p[0], p[1]);
    free_p (p);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ptrp
AAAA BBBB
AAAA BBBB
AAAA BBBB
```

Don't forget to validate your memory use with a memory error checker (such as `valgrind` for Linux). They are simple to use and available for all platforms. Example:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ptrp
==17888== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17888== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17888== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17888== Command: ./bin/ptrp
==17888==
AAAA BBBB
AAAA BBBB
AAAA BBBB
==17888==
==17888== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17888==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17888==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 78 bytes allocated
==17888==
==17888== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17888==
==17888== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17888== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Always confirm *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and equally important *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*.

Comment: Just as an FYI: if you're using Mac OS X, you can't get to 'All heap blocks were freed' because the startup code leaves something over 100 blocks allocated that you can't free — and `valgrind` has to be configured to suppress those. (It is configured when you install it, normally, but it often needs reconfiguring after upgrades).  You can, however, get to 0 bytes in each of the 'definitely lost', 'indirectly lost', 'possibly lost' and 'still reachable' categories — leaving numbers like `suppressed: 26,369 bytes in 189 blocks`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put that in my *"if I'm ever on a mac for something other than banging out an order for a hearing in a hotel lobby"* bag of trick `:)` Seriously .. uugh .. do they not yet have mature exclusion files on mac that make that readout proper, or is that just something left for the user, like with the gtk libraries?